# What public works do I need for my "perfect town"?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I've been trying to achieve *perfect town* rating, but Isabelle keeps telling me that the only thing I need are more public works. The thing is... *I have tons of them*, and yet she tells me I need more!

**Keep in mind that she keeps saying I only need more public works** (town undeveloped), and that I have everything else done: no weeds, clean town, more than 110 trees, more than 78 flowers, 10 villagers, etc...

I've read guides on this, and they say you need at least 10 works without counting the main street/town hall/station. Here is the list of the public works I have in my town:

- 3 Street Lights
- 1 Yellow Bench
- 1 Camping Site
- 1 Water Well
- Original Bridge + 2 more Bridges
- 1 Water Fountain
- 1 Park Clock
- 1 Fence
- 1 Fire Hydrant
- 1 Caution Sign
- 1 Custom-Design Sign
- 1 Face-Cutout Standee
- The Café
- 1 windmill

Is there anything I'm missing? Why am I not getting it?

EDIT: I have over 200 trees. If bamboo and beach trees also count I probably have near 300 tress o.o and flowers are also over 200

Comment: Hm, I'm baffled. I have way, way fewer public works than you and only 9 villagers and I've been maintaining my Perfect Town for almost a month now... :/

Comment: When I go to Isabelle she tells me I need more public works...My shops are all upgraded (not emporium though) and I've got the Café and dream suit...The tree already grew to the point where you can sit and see the town story... Got town clean and full of trees and flowers...Idk what I'm missing

Comment: Maybe there is a specific public works project that must be completed, regardless of how many others there are?

Comment: I dunno what that would be because I have pretty much everything available for me at the moment...the only thing left for me is the 100 visits to get the station re-done but those don't count...I just finished building the windmill and it still tells me I need more public works O_O Do you have to attend all the works celebrations? because I haven't xD I'm also missing the reset center...

Comment: Adding some more info: I haven't got it yet. Still trying...I'd also like to add that I haven't used any kind of cheats nor have I time traveled. I'm playing this fair but it's taking forever to get the god damn perfect town when everyone gets it right away...

Comment: According to this FAQ, http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/997811-animal-crossing-new-leaf/faqs/65246, there are three separate ratings that contribute to your citizen satisfaction.  Two of them ("abundant nature" and "abundant living") each have their own separate lists of good/bad public works projects.  It looks like none of the public works you listed are on the good "abundant nature" list, so maybe she wants you to build more of those.

Answer (score 3):

I can't remember where I read it but some PWP are counted as being negative, Garbage Can and Oil Rig, Tower etc will stop you having a Perfect town. I think only certain decorative items count towards 'Perfect' rating, so try getting rid of your signs and stuff, build fountains and benches, not lamps and clocks etc, see if that works for you? (:

Comment: I also know that one, I read all the guides out there. I had illuminated clock and destroyed it, still no changes. I said it to the last person too, I don't want answers from the guides over the internet I've read them and they are not helping at all.

Comment: That can't be true, because a Yield Sign was what made my town perfect. @AlonsoReche, how spread out are your PWP? Maybe it's a "this many PWP/tree/flowers in this space" thing like in previous AC?

Comment: Pretty spread I'd say. In all the guides I've read they state the acre system is not included in New Leaf.

Answer (score 1):

I have a perfect town, and I don't think I have as many PWP as you do. My experience was that by looking at all my PWP I had a lot of them that were not environmental. I had a lot that gave my town points for abundant living, but next to none that boosted the points for environmental. So I destroyed some of the abundant living PWPs and built some more environmental PWPs and the next day my town was perfect! So you just need an equal amount of environmental PWPs and abundant living PWPs. Hope this helped!

Comment: Yeah... I'm late. Hope you got perfect town rating... Haha

Comment: what does PWP mean?

Comment: PWP means Public Works Projects

Answer (score 0):

I found [this website](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Perfect_Town) that talks about how to achieve "perfect town" status.

Some of the tips were:

1. Plant enough trees and flowers in your town. In Animal Crossing: New Leaf, you need 110-200 trees and over 75 flowers in your town. In games with the acre system you need 12-16 trees and 6-10 flowers planted in each acre. For more variety, add coconut/banana trees and fruit trees where available. Rivers count too, so instead of estimating the space in the river, start from the other side of town.
2. Remove all weeds. About 3-4 weeds spawn daily. Leaving weeds to grow will negatively affect the town status. Dandelions are weeds, too, but count as flowers. Clovers are weeds, but do not bring negative effects to the town's status.
3. Pick up everything lying around your town. They are considered trash and affect the town status. Seashells and fruit do not affect this, although you may want to if you want your town to look tidy.
4. You will need a normal/silver can to water your flowers everyday to prevent wilting. Wilted flowers will affect the town status. Like weeds, 3-4 flowers also spawn daily.
5. In Animal Crossing: New Leaf, Public Works Projects affect the town status. You will need at least 10 projects in your town to acheive the perfect town status, not counting projects in the Main Street or Town Hall/Station upgrades.

My suggestion is that you might have too many trees, or flowers, or maybe even too many public works. I know that I would not want to live in a town that is very crowded, but that might just be me.

Comment: It's not that I have too many public works for sure, Isabelle keeps asking me for that, if you read my message you'd know that. Second, I tried chopping down trees and bamboos to 180 and I'm still not getting it. Flowers everyone everywhere said you can never have too many. Oh and I've already read too many times the piece of info you pasted from the wiki. So my problem has to be something else, I've already read all the guides on the internet what I'm looking for here are personal answers from your experience with perfect town.

Comment: Giving up on it, it could be glitched for all I know... I'll just go on playing and hope one day I get it.

Comment: @Alonso Reche Is it possible that she actually means you have too many public works, but the dialogue for that is glitched so that she SAYS that you have too many? Seems like a translation error that could happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of some of your trees.  I read on another forum where a person had a similar problem, and it was because they had too many trees.  Once they had the 200~ trees, they had a perfect town.

It seems to me that the needed flowers and trees balance out with the public works, so it can be bad to have too many.  You need more public works in order to balance out the massive amount of trees you have, so getting rid of trees may help.  This is just a guess though.

Comment: Per [this comment](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126909/whats-missing-for-my-perfect-town#comment173226_127373) he has tried with trees <200.

Comment: Read last answer I gave, I'm already at 180 trees, counted them. Built the reset center and another street lamp and it's still not perfect town...but thank you a lot at first I thought that'd be my problem but it has to be something else.