# How can I get a perfect town?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I have tons of bushes, trees, flowers and public work projects. But Isabelle says my town is still a dump. I don't have any garbage in my town. Anyone know what to do?

Comment: Possible dupes: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/128259/what-are-the-greenery-requirements-for-a-perfect-town-rating, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126909/what-public-works-do-i-need-for-my-perfect-town?s=2|6.2968

Answer (score 1):

If you have public work projects that give off a bright lights, such as the street lights and that massive TV-Billboard thing, that could be the reason why you can't get a perfect town.  You can demolish them by asking Isabelle when you sit in the mayors chair.